# Facing an issue with process.start(); in Android Lollipop

Tags: java, android

Facing an issue with `process.start();` in Android Lollipop

I am facing an issue with android lollipop background process inside a service. my code is working fine until KitKat.

i have a `ProcessBuilder pBuilder` and assigned a command into it, and starting the process builder by

```
Process proc = pBuilder.start();

int exitCode = proc.waitFor();
```

In lollipop the exitCode is always return "1" that menace failed.

is there any other way to do the same on android lollipop.

**My code looks like :**

```
final List<String> cmd = new LinkedList<String>();
cmd.add(mFfmpegPath);
cmd.add("-i");
cmd.add(inputPath);
cmd.add("-ss");
cmd.add(videoStartTime);        
cmd.add("-t");
cmd.add(videoDuration); 
cmd.add("-vcodec");
cmd.add("copy");
cmd.add("-acodec");
cmd.add("copy");
cmd.add(outputPath);
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
return new ProcessRunnable(pb);
```

**Runnable class contain..**

```
private final ProcessBuilder pBuilder;
public ProcessRunnable(ProcessBuilder process){
pBuilder = process;
}

Process proc = null;
proc = pBuilder.start();
int exitCode = pro.waitFor();
```

Thanks

Comment: This should work. You could also try the example from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html). Maybe the commands you are using are not available on Lollipop?

Comment: @vishnupriyan, were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i have fixed the issue,
This was due to my armeabi version, i have update it to armeabi-v7a and make some changes as described in below link.
And worked both Android kitkat and lollipop version.

[Please follow this link](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html)