# Issues with android-ffmpeg on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing, android-4.4-kitkat, android-5.0-lollipop

I am working on an application which mixes audio and video.

I am following [android-ffmpeg guardianproject](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg) to solve my purpose. The issue is that it works fine till Android `Kitkat`. But the process fails on Android `Lollipop`.

Here is my code to run the process

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
pb.directory(fileExec);

//  pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();    

// any error message?
StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new 
StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR", sc);            

// any output?
StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new 
StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT", sc);

// kick them off
errorGobbler.start();
outputGobbler.start();

int exitVal = process.waitFor();
sc.processComplete(exitVal);
return exitVal;
```

How can i solve this for Lollipop? Are there any additional files that i should include for solving this for `Lollipop`?

Comment: I am also seeing this issue

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076473/facing-an-issue-with-process-start-in-android-lollipop/27476746#27476746), I was able to solve the issue by replacing ffmpeg android library.

They are providing Android Lollipop support. You can refer to this [link](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html).